# Angular - cannot access items in the database through the methods in the component which should be called when the page loads

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angular5

In my service file, I have a get method to return data form a collection to an array. I want to have another method in my component (front-end controller) which need to access those data from the data base before the page loads. So I use it like below (books is the array to store data from the database)

```
refreshBookList() {

this.bookService.getBookList().subscribe((res) => {
this.books = res as Book[];
console.log(this.books);}); 
}
```

I need to do this when the page loads. so I call it like

```
ngOnInit() {    
this.refreshBookList();    
}
```

But it only returns an empty array. The data gets added to the array only if the method is called from a button click in the interface. Is there any way I could get the result at page initialization.

Comment: can you provide code snippet through plunker or something?

Comment: Try using https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rdh8eh to provide code snippets that reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to call the method inside [AfterViewInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit)

Comment: Thank you for this useful tip :) but it didn't work for me :/  saving my book list, books in local storage finally worked.